# How to create images from screen and find them at screen?

Tags: c#, bitmap, screen

I was using a tool called simba which had libraries for pascal, the functions I was using are called and used like this:

```
bitmapfromscreen(x, y, x', y') : integer
findbitmapin(bmp, x, y, x', y') : boolean
```

I began learning c# but I couldn't find find similar functions for visual C#  (there is this function getpixel but i couldn't produce anything that works) I looked at a number of examples that employ similar processes but they were rather complex programs which i couldn't sort out. If there is a way to do these jobs, could you tell, show, or give links to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this method for copying from screen?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The code I've found on the internet looks like this:

```
public Bitmap PrintScreen()
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 500, 360);//Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        int color = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
        PixelFormat pFormat;
        switch (color)
        {
            case 8:
            case 16:
                pFormat = PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565;
                break;

            case 24:
                pFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                break;

            case 32:
                pFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                break;

            default:
                pFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                break;
        }
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, pFormat);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Then in your code you can do this:

```
Bitmap screenImage = PrintScreen();
```